# Get all futures that finish within a set period of time?

Tags: java, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

I have a list of callables and I want to start them all in parallel, give them 5 seconds to complete, and use the results from any of the tasks that finish within that time.

I tried using executorService.invokeAll with a timeout, but in this case they all need to finish before my timeout.

What is the best way to do this using Java 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the answers helped me get to the solution.  The issue with Logeart's answer is that I want to give them a max time - so if they finish quicker, I get them all (sorry if this wasn't clear in the question).

The other issue is that isDone() does not catch the case when a task is cancelled - you need to use isCancelled().  So, my working solution was:

```
 ExecutorService exectutorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
 List<Callable<Object>> callables = Arrays.asList(
            (Callable(Object) new Check1Callable(),
            (Callable(Object) new Check2Callable(),
            (Callable(Object) new Check3Callable());

 List<Future<Object>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

 try {
     futures = executorService.invokeAll(callables,maxWaitTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 } catch (Exception e) {
 }

 for (Future thisFuture : futures) {
    try {
        if (thisFuture.isDone() && !thisFuture.isCancelled()) {
           <accept the future's result>
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

What I do is submit all the tasks and add the Futures to a list.

You can then wait for the timeout, and get all the Futures where `isDone()` is true.

Alternatively you can call get on each of the Futures which a decreasing timeout based on the amount of time remaining.

Answer (score 1):

Just check after 5s if the `Future` is terminated  using `isDone`:

```
List<Callable<V>> callables = // ...
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(callables.size()));
List<Future<V>> futures = es.invokeAll(callables);

// Wait 5s
Thread.sleep(5000);

List<V> terminatedResults = new ArrayList<>();
for(Future<V> f : futures) {
    if(f.isDone()) {
        terminatedResults.add(f.get());
    } else {
        // cancel the future?
    }
}
// use terminatedResults
```